# How to close the cmd prompt window automatically after a batch file execution

Tags: batch-file

**UPDATE: Problem fixed (I posted my answer)**

I created a batch file that opens up a Python script and runs it. Everything is working great, but the command prompt window stays open at the end.
I've tried a few different things, which were basically playing around with the following 2:

1. `start "" "*file location*"`
2. `exit` at the end of the file

As of the latest thing I tried, the batch file includes:

```
start /min C:\Users\rricklis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:\Users\rricklis\PycharmProjects\AutomateInvoices\InvoiceStatus.py
exit
```

- `start ... InvoiceStatus.py` is all on the first line
- `exit` is on the second line

Any ideas why the `cmd` is still not closing?

Comment: are you using `start` with /w argument?

Comment: I sounds more like your python script is opening a separate `cmd.exe` instance. What happens if you use `Start /Min /B …` and remove the unnecessary second line? _(A batch file should generally `exit` when there's no further commands to run)_. If you want the window to remain open until after the python script has finishes, you don't use `Start`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out my python script wasn't fully closed- it was still running in task manager, so that's why the command prompt window wasn't able to close yet.

For anyone who might need it:
I was using python selenium in my script. At the end of the program, I had to switch my code : `browser.close() to browser.quit()` so that the `chromedriver.exe` wasn't still running in task manager.

Comment: Thank you! This was my issue exactly and it was driving me crazy.

Comment: you're a god send. I've been on this for 20 minutes

Answer (score 0):

exit command in this case won't work without arguments so I suggest you try:

```
exit /b
```

it will force the cmd window to close

Comment: I tried that but still wasn't working. Just posted my problem and solution^^ thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the start command is opening up your python interpreter.

I simply write like this

1. `"C:\Users\abhic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" 
   "C:\Users\abhic\Documents\sample.py"`
2. `exit`

The first part in line 1 is the python interpreter location and the second inverted comma's contain the script location and second line is for exiting the cmd.
My python version is 3.6 .